# Give a warning when using mkdir in a certain directory

Tags: linux, file-permissions

Is there any way to give a warning when a user tries to use mkdir when in a certain directory? There are supposed to be shared folders, but someone will make a subdirectory and forget to chmod it, so other users are unable to write or read from the subdirectory.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the filesystem, you should be able to set *default ACLs* which would make newly created subdirectories open:

```
setfacl -d -m u::rwx,g::rwx,o::rwx /path/to/directory
```

Comment: I'm getting `Operation not supported`. Currently running Ubuntu64 12.04 LTS. I'm a little bit wary of enabling ACLs in /etc/fstab. Would this change how permissions work on any other files?

Comment: @StevenMorad Your file system probably does not have ACLs enabled. You might need to add the `acl` option in your `/etc/fstab` for the mount you want to use it on.

Comment: @StevenMorad: No, it won't affect existing files at all. More recent kernels enable this option by default.

Answer (score 2):

How about aliasing `mkdir` to a script?

```
alias mkdir=/usr/local/bin/mkdir-safe
```

`mkdir-safe` would then be something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
for arg; do
    case $(readlink -m "$arg") in
        /home/shared/folders/*)
            echo "warning: Creating subdirectory in shared directory." >&2
            ;;
    esac
done
mkdir "$@"
```

Comment: @grawity - does this cater for when you are in the shared folder already and just do `mkdir newfolder`

Comment: You could of course code the chmod right in there (with a message it was chmod'ed). (At least i think that was the whole point)

Comment: @Paul: The `readlink` call will always return an absolute path, so yes.